# Can't get webpack hot middleware working with react/redux

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

IM pulling out hairs trying to get hot reloading working. My project loads when I run `node server.js` but files are not being hot reloaded.

#### server.js

```
// webpack stuff
var webpack = require("webpack");
var webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
var webpackHotMiddleware = require("webpack-hot-middleware");
var config = require("./webpack.config");
var compiler = webpack(config);

// email template
var emailTemplate = require("./emailTemplate");

// express
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var crypto = require("crypto");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var port = 8000;

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/src"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
....... shorten for security
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/src/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    public: '/',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8000/public/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname + '/src'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      }
    ]
  },
  jest: {
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Please let me know if there are other files that would be useful to see.